# How to prevent my DbContext from running out of available pooled connections when used within a ServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, dependency-injection

I've written a aspnet core console application that uses Entity Framework Core with SQL Server. The application has several Azure Service Bus queue clients, which I assume each run the message receiver handler within their own threads - so it's a threaded application within that third party Service Bus library, I believe.

To avoid configuring and creating SQL connections within each Service Bus queue client, I'm using dependency injection with a `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection`. I then pass the resulting `ServiceProvider` down into each Service Bus queue client.

My problem is that, over time, my program quits working because the SQL connection pool runs out of available connections. It's like a memory leak, but it's a SQL connection leak because the connections are never released back to the pool, I suppose.

I've read into this a bit, and to my understanding the connection should just go back to the pool when it goes out of scope. I've also read that threading may cause these issues, which is why I brought up the Service Bus queue client and the fact that I believe the message handler runs from within a thread.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking, but I've not been able to fix it after trying a few different approaches. I will paste my code below, and then explain some of the things I've tried.

So, here is the code that configures and creates the `ServiceProvider` ...

```
private ServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddDbContext<WibWorkspaceContext>(ConfigureDbContext, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

And then here is the `ConfigureDbContext` method that the above code uses ...

```
private void ConfigureDbContext(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(WibWorkspaceContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
    var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sql"];

    options
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString.ConnectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
}
```

And I pass that `ServiceProvider` down into each Service Bus message handler, in which I make my call to `GetRequiredService`. So, I do believe my call to `GetRequiredService` occurs within the thread created by the Service Bus client. Below is some snipped code of that ...

```
private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var sql = m_services.GetRequiredService<WibWorkspaceContext>();

    ...
}
```

Within `ProcessMessagesAsync` I make use of the `DbContext` but I never do anything relating to disposing it or anything. I just allow it to go out of scope and that's it.

And so this is my code. This program will run just fine until it begins to run out of SQL connections. At that point it begins to throw the following error and stack trace ...

> 2020-10-02 23:07:55.1660 ERROR Timeout expired.  The timeout period
> elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
> occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
> was reached.

```
2020-10-02 23:07:15.3764 ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WhatInBoxWorkerService.Queues.CreateRelativityPackageQueueClient.ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\rcole\Projects\WhatInBox\src\Applications\WhatInBoxWorkerService\Queues\CreateRelativityPackageQueueClient.cs:line 203
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump.MessageDispatchTask(Message message)
```

And as you would expect, the program begins to crash because no connections can be retrieved from the connection pool.

One thing I did try, but did not seem to make any difference, was to use `AddDbContextPool` instead of `AddDbContext`.

Am I forgetting to do anything?

Comment: So many things it could be without seeing the entirety of the code... But the first thing that springs to mind would be to ask how long the object you're injecting the dbcontext into is alive for, including caching it in memory or the session etc ... The connection will stay open until the the parent class is disposed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there is an issue with your dependency injection setup, in here:

```
var sql = m_services.GetRequiredService<WibWorkspaceContext>();
```

If that `m_services` is the root container which you never dispose and base on your comment

> Within ProcessMessagesAsync I make use of the DbContext but **I never do anything relating to disposing it or anything**. I just allow it to go out of scope and that's it.

then you may end up with all the `WibWorkspaceContext`s never get disposed.

**Why?**

I assume you use the Microsoft extensions DI. Transient/Scoped services are only disposed when their *scope* ends. If you resolve them from the root container, they will not be disposed until the container is disposed. That's why [resolving transient `IDisposable` from root container isn't recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#general-idisposable-guidelines).

To fix this, you might need a custom scope:

```
using(var scope = m_services.CreateScope())
{
    var sql = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<WibWorkspaceContext>();

} // <--- Your DB context will be disposed here
```